# C# deleting a directory as another user

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to write a small service to delete one directory and all the files contained within it, there is one issue which I don't know how to resolve which is that the users don't have persmissions to access the folder or update it, so I'm trying to run the delete as an administrator from within AD. Is there any way I can do this from within a service? As the service will be run on the system login via a small script to start it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is not community wiki

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can expose the native "LogonUser" methods and use them to impersonate logging on as another user. I've used this successfully in other projects.

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUserName, String lpszDomain,
    String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
```

Fresh Click Media did an article about this and wrote a sample Impersonate class: --> http://www.freshclickmedia.com/blog/2008/11/programmatic-impersonation-in-c/

Using it is quite simple:

```
using (Impersonator impersonator = new Impersonator())
{
    // code in here
}
```

Comment: Great answer!  The link has slightly changed, though.  I found it at http://freshclickmedia.co.uk/2008/11/programmatic-impersonation-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

If it's running as a Windows Service, the service can be given specific credentials when it is installed. Or are you asking about a small stand alone app that is only going to be run at startup?

In other words, are you talking about an installed Windows Service or a stand alone app?

Comment: It wants to be a small stand alone that will only run after login as its to delete a directory that might exist from the previous user as were implementating virtualized applications and need to delete the sandbox directory there run in.